# JavaScript custom tooltips

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding a tooltips using JavaScript code

```
$(function(){
$('.fimg2').mousemove(function(e){
$('.fimgshow2').fadeIn();
$('.fimgshow2').css('top', e.clientY+20).css('left', e.clientX+10);
}).mouseout(function(){
$('.fimgshow2').hide();
$('.fimgshow2').fadeOut();
});
});
```

Here fimg2 is a image. when we mouse move on that image then fimgshow2 should be apper as tool tips.

It's working file but position of the fimgshow2 div not appearing at left side of mouse.

When i move page up or down then position of fimgshow2 also changed.

At last I want to set dynamic position to "fimgshow2" using
    $('.fimgshow2').css('top', e.clientY+20).css('left', e.clientX+10);

when i can show tool tips in just right side of mouse pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a fiddle for you [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7F3Rj/)

```
<img class="fimg2" src="somelink" style="position:absolute"></img>
<img class="fimgshow2" src="someotherlink" style="position:relative;display:none"></img>
```

I think you are not setting the position of both the image.

The position of figm2 and fimgshow2 should be absolute and relative respectively.

Hope I am not missing anything.